# Oracle SQL compare two tables data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables A,B in my oracle db and I want to compare data of both tables based on unique field (userid) but B table contains user IDs as Puserid (P appended for all IDs)

How to use where condition in above case for two tables to retrieve data?

Answer (score 2):

You may use `ltrim` :

```
select a.*, b.*
  from tableA a join tableB b on ( a.userid = ltrim(b.userid,'P') );
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically, "P" is *prepended*, not appended.

You can just use `||`:

```
from a join
     b
     on b.userId = 'P' || a.userId
```

This could have a big impact on performance.  If you are able, you should define a new column in `b` (perhaps a virtual column).  The above can use an index on `b(userid)`.

You can also phrase this as:

```
from a join
     b
     on a.userId = substr(b.userId, 2)
```

And this can make use of an index on `a(userid)`.